# what's the purpose of spark sql over hive?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, tez

I know the question had been asked years ago, but I am still wondering the true purpose of using SparkSQL / HiveContext.

Spark approach gives a more generic distributed way that the built-in MapReduce.

I read a lot of articles claiming that MR way is already dead and Spark is the best (I understand that I can implement an MR approach through Spark).

When it is recommended to query data using HiveContext, I am a little bit confused.

Indeed, running a query from SparkSQL/HiveContext doesn't it imply running a MR job ? Isn't it to back to the main problematic ? TEZ isn't it enought if I don't need to encapsulate the query result in more complex code ?

Am I wrong (I am sure I am :-)) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Indeed, running a query from SparkSQL/HiveContext doesn't it imply running a MR job ?

It does not. In fact using `HiveContext` or `SparkSession` with "Hive support" doesn't imply any connection to Hive, other than using Hive metastore. This approach is used by many other systems, both ETL solutions and databases.

Finally:

- Hive is a database with modular components. It supports relatively rich permissions system, mutations and transactions.
- Spark is general purpose processing engine. Despite having SQL-ish component it doesn't attempt to be a database.